# Stats for close options?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any statistics for the various close options? Additionally how many questions of each close type are eventually reopened?

If not globally available, can a mod post the information for us?

Comment: I don't have access to that information directly. If you didn't need specific close reasons, you could probably craft something up in the StackExchange Data Explorer (data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Don't have time to write anything at the moment but you can also get the close reason from data explorer, in PostHistory where PostHistoryTypeID = 10 the comment column contains a number that indicates the reason. There's a list of them here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt at a data explorer query based on a few existing queries. The month shown is based on the creation date of the original post not the date it was actually closed or re-opened. I haven't given it much of a check over but the results look fairly plausible.

[Monthly totals of questions closed / re-opened by close reason](http://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/174837/monthly-totals-of-questions-closed-re-opened-by-close-reason)

Just a few notes:

- The data explorer extract happens early on a Monday morning I believe so the current month results can be up to a week out of date.
- Deleted posts aren't exported to the data dump, so older data will be skewed because many of the closed questions will have been deleted as per [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Answer (score 0):

Found something on meta.so, had to play with the filters to show the data.

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=2014-03-01&todate=2014-03-14&order=desc&sort=activity&closed=True&filter=!)4rx.eTsSSR1zWcYugLAn5C3EYgk&site=electronics&run=true

Example result:

> {
>         "closed_details": {
>           "on_hold": true,
>           "description": "This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:    Questions on the **repair** of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: "Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?" – Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, PeterJ, alexan_e, Joe Hass, Dave Tweed\r\n    ",
>           "reason": "off-topic"
>         },
>         "creation_date": 1394696962,
>         "link": "[Have I destroyed my device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102760/have-i-destroyed-my-device)",
>         "closed_reason": "off-topic",
>         "title": "Have I destroyed my device"
>       },